# how to adding google maps location to my website

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-markers

I use Laravel 8.x and I added google maps to my project on localhost. I got this error:

[image]

In HTML

```
<div id="map" class="gmaps"></div>
```

and added script javascript from google to load  the maps

[https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete&language=ar&region=LB)

```
 <script
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key={{{{{{ MY API KEY from google }}}}}}&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
      async
    ></script
```

This is API activate

[image]

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: What error message do you get in the javascript console?  You will need to address that.

Comment: Geocoding Service: You must enable Billing on the Google Cloud Project at https://console.cloud.google.com/project/_/billing/enable Learn more at https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started
_.Ee @ js?key=AIzaSyBGP2Z4owZlWQDRXcdqQgVImlHJedrhefE&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete                async defer:81

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include that information.  Have you done that (enabled billing)?

Answer (score -3):

Well I don't know much so don't blame on me for doing it wrong but on the Google Maps website you can get the html code without having to do it yourself
[A photo:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYokU.jpg)

It will look something like this

```html
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m24!1m12!1m3!1d37884.27437429994!2d10.038146266404057!3d53.5976162881659!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!4m9!3e1!4m3!3m2!1d53.605531199999994!2d10.0321597!4m3!3m2!1d53.605892999999995!2d10.1306738!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1630424037937!5m2!1snl!2snl" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. but i want to get exact location

Comment: This is in no way related to the question.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.